# Multiple Search Buttons in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

There are a few questions on SO about multiple submit buttons, such as [How do you handle multiple submit buttons in ASP.NET MVC Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework) but what I am having trouble with is having multiple search buttons, each with it's own associated textbox for the value being searched for, and which searches it's own set of data. For example..

```
    <div class="leftContentColumnRow">
        @Html.TextBox("SearchString", null, new { placeholder = "Search Roles..." })

        <input type="submit" value="" class="searchbtn" name="SearchRoles" />
    </div>

    <div class="rightContentColumnRow">
        @Html.TextBox("SearchString", null, new { placeholder = "Search Permissions..." })
        <input type="submit" value="" class="searchbtn" name="SearchPermissions" />
    </div>
```

I can determine which button has been clicked, but I am struggling to get hold of the data in both textboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Oded said, 2 forms, each has it'w own action paramter value.

```
@using(Html.Beginform("SearchRole","User")
{
    <div class="leftContentColumnRow">
        @Html.TextBox("SearchString", null, new { placeholder = "Search Roles..." })

        <input type="submit" value="" class="searchbtn" name="SearchRoles" />
    </div>
}
@using(Html.Beginform("SearchPermissions","User")
{
    <div class="rightContentColumnRow">
        @Html.TextBox("SearchString", null, new { placeholder = "Search Permissions..." })
        <input type="submit" value="" class="searchbtn" name="SearchPermissions" />
    </div>
}
```

and the Action methods

```
public ActionResult SearchRole(string SearchString)
{
  //get data and return something
}
public ActionResult SearchPermissions(string SearchString)
{
  //get data and return something
}
```

Comment: I should just comment, make sure you do not nest forms.  Nested forms is not legal HTML.  (the code above is not nested, I just want to make it clear that this should not be done).

Comment: Thanks. That answers my question - the fact I have to work out the results, presumably with some partial views is my problem :) Thanks.

MM yep got that thanks.
Oded cheers - Shyju fleshed it out by the time I took a look..

Answer (score 2):

Use a separate form for each `input` `button` pair with a different `action` for the form.